# Is it appropriate ask for a raise three months after getting hired?

Tags: software-industry, salary, career-development, graduate

I am a fresh graduate and I got hired for a testing position. On the job advertisement, the starting salary was 850€. Three months later the advertisement now says that the starting salary is 1000€ on the same position in the same company. I feel a little deflated, since the difference of 150€ seems too big and arbitrary.

Is it appropriate to ask my boss for a raise? If so, how can I formulate this request?

Comment: The only thing it shows is that the firm is *willing* to pay up to that amount for your position. So you could, eventually ask for a raise, but not before you understand what they are looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Comment: Is it the exact same position? Were you hired at 850?

Comment: Yes it is same pos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing is that you can't obviously just say : You give the other one 1000€ so I want the same, maybe you both are doing the same thing, but his skills when negotiating the salary is far better than you. In lots of situations, negociation skills can make difference between people because work is not 100% about what you can do, there's also the soft skills part, including communication, management, leadership, dealing with urgent situations ...

IF I WERE IN YOUR SHOES, and I confirm that this is only my opinion, I would wait between 6 to 12 months before asking for a raise, during that time I would've built some solid arguments to negociate the raise : e.g : I've been working hard during the past months and I was able to perform 20%, or don't know how much, that's why I think ...
The other thing I want to tell is to work on your soft skills, communication is important, words are important, knowing how to talk is important. Sometimes other people are getting offers not because they're technical skills are better but it's just because they knew how to convince the interviewers that they're the best candidates for the position.

Good luck.

Comment: Yes I will wait rather do something wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> Is it appropriate to ask my boss for a raise?

Sure, you can *ask* for a raise at any time.  However, you need to be prepared to justify your request.  The *frequency* of such requests outside of the annual review process needs to be carefully done.

> If so, how can I formulate this request?

"*Boss, I just noticed that a new hire in my role is getting paid a whole lot more.  Is there anyway you can adjust my salary accordingly?*"

The rub here is that your **boss may say no**, so mentally be prepared for that.  But in the situation you have outlined, you have a strong case to at least **ask**, based on my experience.

Comment: If an annual review process was agreed on. In some parts of the world there's a trial period for the new job (6 months maybe). You discuss payment then.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  It is appropriate.  Bring to the meeting evidence of your accomplishments and added value over the past 3 months and cite the advertisement.  Be prepared to be refused though - and if that happens ask what you are lacking and what they are looking for that they feel warrants the higher salary.

Answer (score 2):

1. Are you being paid what was agreed upon?   If so, you really have no reason to expect more.
2. You're a brand new graduate.   Do you know that the new hires will be brand new grads?  Or will they have more experience?   If so, why do you expect to be paid the same for less experience?

The same thing happened to me years ago.  I was in a position where the company boosted the minimum pay to a few cents per hour above my current wage.   But the guy who was recently hired, with 2 years less experience got a $3/hour raise out of it.   It didn't seem fair to be paid the same as him when I knew I was doing the job better.

But you can't control that. You can only control the job you do.

Could you ask for a raise?   Sure.    Would they give it?   Maybe.  They might be planning to already.    Personally, I'd be happy to have the job.

Comment: Interesting viewpoint compared to my answer.  It boils down to are you content or are you ambitious.  The OP is clearly ambitious, and based on the question they are looking for reasons to act on their ambition.  Also "be happy to have the job" undermines the value of the individual.  Turn this on its head: the job is lucky to have them!

Comment: It's a recent new grad.   Personally, the first job for MOST people after college is a stepping-stone position.   They are getting experience to move on to a better paying job.

Comment: Yes I have not enough experiences in the area (IT sector).

Comment: "Be happy to have the job" is very good assertivity, especially in my country generally. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All new hires get better deal than already acquired ones. It happens on all levels.
There may be some market issues that prompted higher salary to attract more candidates.
Usually 3 months is the length of probationary period. If you are due to some review with your supervisor you can try to tackle the topic.
If not check what your contract says about rise. For example if you are eligible for one raise a year and the max raise can 10% of what you make that would be the obvious discourage for you to stay hat long in company if even after that you would get less than someone hired 4 month after you.

Check the advertisement if it have the same specs as your job. If yes talk with your boss if your performance is lacking in something that would prohibit you from getting that "new" position with higher salary.